# How to find all topics on Stack Overflow that contain one of the words from a list

Tags: discussion, search

I want to find all topics on Stack Overflow that contain either word "one" or word "two". In other words I need logical OR for my search query.

I couldn't find anything appropriate among the advanced search options. However it says that you can use wildcard, which may imply some support for regular expressions.

Does anyone know how to deal with that kind of advanced queries of the website?

Comment: This may help? http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: I read this before asking this question. It only mentions OR on tags but not on the phrases.

Comment: Hmm - I get distinctly different results for [`topic or word`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=topic+or+word) and [`topic and word`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=topic+and+word), but unfortunately [`topic word`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=topic+word) should logically have been one of these two...

Comment: @Jongware, should indeed! But all the three searches return different number of matches!? I think "or" and "and" are considered as a part of the search string.

Comment: Last I checked this is elastic search, have any of you tamed elastic search before?  Its not that simple!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the on-site search doesn't provide the type of control you would like to have over search terms and its results you can fallback to [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

For example this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/618563?search=one%2Ctwo) will search for one or more terms in an *or* fashion

```
-- --search:separate terms with a comma
declare  @searchterms nvarchar(200) = ##search:string##

select distinct top 100
       id as [Post Link]
from posts p
inner join string_split(@searchterms,',') as st on p.body like '%' + st.value + '%'
where creationdate > '2016-01-01'
and score > 10
```

Keep in mind that SEDE is not optimized for full text searches so you better either restrict the number of rows returned or use additional where clauses to restrict the search scope, in the example creationdate and score are used.

SEDE is only updated once a week, on Sunday morning.